# Angular ActivatedRoute, paramMap.get('id') not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript

so basically i want tho get something from my server using the id of the object.

The id is also in the url:

```
http://xyz/detail/5ee8cb8398e9a44d0df65455
```

So now im trying the following in xyz.component.ts:

```
  getEx(): void {
    let id:string = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    const x = this.exService.getEx(id)
      .subscribe(ex => this.ex = ex);
  }
```

But this does not work because paramMap.get returns a number and not a string.

> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

The last part of my url is obv a string, how can i get this string?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do think `5ee8cb8398e9a44d0df65455` could be converted to a number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`route.snapshot.paramMap.get` returns string only. You seem to have added the `+` before that which is converting that to int.

It should simply be:

```
let id:string = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

Comment: Thanks :) i copied the code from the docs and never noticed the '+'

Comment: What if I want to convert the string to integer? :)

My code is giving me the error that object is possibly null, although ActivatedRouter in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
id: any;

constructor(public route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.id = params['id'];
   })
}
```

It can read id from the link format:
localhost:4200/componentname?id=abcdef

and will return value abcdef in the id variable

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `+` sign from `+this.route` in your code. In this way it is trying to convert the `id` which is string to `int`.

That's why it's throwing `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)` error

```
getEx(): void {
    let id:string = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    const x = this.exService.getEx(id)
      .subscribe(ex => this.ex = ex);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the problem.